# Background для изображения

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать background контейнера так, чтобы картинка была на всю ширину экрана, а контент был по середине. К примеру как на этом сайте http://settleorder.com/en/  ? Мне важно, чтобы верстка была адаптивной, но изображение показывало соответственно.

Answer (score 1):

```
Background: url('картинка') no-repeat; background-size: cover;
```

Так можно настроить фоновую картинку на всю ширину и высоту экрана, присвойте это значение к body и готово.

Центрирование на данном сайте работает через центрированный по центру див и отступом сверху. Значит так:
Сначала центрируем блок с контентом по горизонтали:

```
width: 936px; /* ширина обязательна для того что бы работала следующая строка */
margin: 0 auto; /* центрирует блок по горизонтали относительно ширины внешнего блока */
position: relative; /* абсолютное позиционирование в дочернем блоке не работает без относительного в родителе */
height: 100%; /* важно что бы было 100%, иначе мы не сможем правильно центрировать по вертикали */
```

Теперь вертикаль:

```
position: absolute; /* абсолютное позиционирование */
width: 936px; 
left: 0;
top: 50%; /* отступ сверху ровно на половину */
margin-top: -128px; /* центрируем блок */
```

Answer (score 0):

Картинка должна быть большой, чтобы закрывать 100% и ширины, и высоты экрана.

```
.block {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: url(http://settleorder.com/static/index/images/bg-page1.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

[Пример работы здесь.](https://jsfiddle.net/NeedHate/ewfa5oev/3/)